# Import ParseUI-Android github repo into Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio, parse-platform

I am having trouble getting my gradle to build properly after I import the ParseUI-Android github repo

1. I clone the repo down locally
2. I update the submodule (run git submodule update --init --recursive while in ParseUI-Android local repo)
3. I put the repo into my project (at the same level as app)

Here is the error I receive:
    Error:Error:line (4)Project with path ':facebook-sdk:facebook' could not be found in project ':ParseUI-Android:ParseLoginUI'.

Project Structure:

```
TestingOutBeta
---app
   ---libs (I put the general Parse jar file in here and it works fine)
   ---build.gradle
---ParseUI-Android
   ---facebook-sdk
      ---build.gradle
   ---build.gradle
---build.gradle
---settings.gradle
```

In my top level build.gradle I have:

```
//Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

In my top level settings.gradle I have:

```
include ':app', ":ParseUI-Android:ParseLoginUI", ":ParseUI-Android:facebook-sdk:facebook"
```

in my app level build.gradle I have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sammyxer.testingoutbeta"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile project(":ParseUI-Android:ParseLoginUI")
}
```

in my ParseUI-Android level build.gradle I have:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19
    buildToolsVersion = "19.1.0"

    minSdkVersion = 8
    targetSdkVersion = 19
}
```

Any tips or help would be great! Thanks everybody

Comment: i guess u need to import some lib there..right click project-->go to properties-->Android-->see there is any lib import with cross mark?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is extremely confusing especially if you're following their instructions and grabbing the facebook-sdk "folder" which is actually a github repo within the ParseLoginUI-Android repo on github.

1. Until you can figure out how to point directly at each repo through git(hub), I recommend a static import through download, see steps 2 and 3.
2. Read the Facebook documentation for Android
3. Download the facebook SDK from here: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip  - Last night they released 3.18
4. Make your project structure look like this (see image link below) in Android Studio until you've got it working through git (or in the unlikely event before you publish that there's any documentation on Android Studio w/ Parse.)

Project structure SCREENSHOT:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWgE9.png - I'll update this with the image itself after I get 10+ reputation

NOTE: To get your app working when you actually touch `facebook login`, you'll need to create an app as a facebook developer to get an application ID as you'll notice in `strings.xml` of your `ParseLoginUI/res/values/` directory. Also, while I haven't needed to use facebook login for any Android apps I've developed yet, you'll likely need to use the Java keytool AND provide the main activity you want facebook to launch as indicated here